# Smooth option in Blender 2.8 mesh context menu missing for edges and faces

Tags: mesh, interface, edit-mode

In Blender 2.79, it was possible to apply "Smooth" from the mesh context menu in vertex, edge and face mode.

**For Blender 2.79**

Vertex mode:

[image: Smooth in Vertex mode (Blender 2.79)]

Edge mode:

[image: Smooth in Edge mode (Blender 2.79)]

Face mode:

[image: Smooth in Face mode (Blender 2.79)]

However, in the recently released Beta for 2.8, this option was removed for edges and faces.

**For Blender 2.8:**

Vertex mode:

[image: Smooth in Vertex mode (Blender 2.8)]

Edge mode:

[image: No Smooth in Edge mode (Blender 2.8)]

Face mode:

[image: No Smooth in Face mode (Blender 2.8)]

Sometimes I want to smooth not single vertices, but larger areas. The only workaround I can come up with at this point is to select faces in Face mode and then change to Vertex mode before smoothing.

The Smooth option in the context menu was extremely convenient in Blender 2.79 and I don't really know why the developers would remove this functionality when it worked perfectly. Has it maybe been relocated to another menu?

Comment: I think this kind of cries are for bug reports, not for community to solve. Yes, maybe it's just me, but what can users do, not being the Blender core devs?

Comment: Yes, I agree completely! Before I submit a bug report, I was just wondering if there was a menu I overlooked.

Comment: Maybe being in any mode you can call menus for vertex, edge or face (with Ctrl+V, Ctrl+E, Ctrl+F respectively), like in older versions. I cannot check it though.

Comment: Yes, that works! If your comment was posted as a an answer, I'd upvote it. :P

Comment: ok, it's easy peasy )

Answer (score 2):

Like in older versions, you can call menus for vertex, edge or face (with Ctrl+V, Ctrl+E, Ctrl+F respectively), being in any selection mode. And, as you say, it really works. :-)

Comment: Thank for the tip! I also submitted a bug report to the development team, so let's see if something changes for future releases (to be honest, it does seem like a very minor issue...).